# How are chances of winning pot worked out?

Tags: odds

http://uk.pokernews.com/poker-tools/poker-odds-calculator.htm

The website link above calculates odds for winning with a certain hand and the percentages are adjusted based on how many players haven't folded and of course, the cards shown on the flop/turn/river.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me as to how these percentages are worked out. e.g. if you have AA, why is it an 85% chance of winning against one opponent (without knowing their hand)? How do they adjust the percentage for 2,3,4 players etc? Also, how does it change when you enter in the villains hand e.g. your AA vs their KK?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of them run X number of random deals. [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)  Typically with [R](https://www.r-project.org/about.html). They will do some advanced stuff.

There are like 10^60 possible boards but only 2.1 million unique combinations. The order does not matter. So they will take random combinations or possibly all combinations.

I made one and just run 10,000 random deals and it seem to be within 1%.  My plan was to sell it as a Windows Store App but it is not fast enough even at 1%.

You can get libraries - [PokerStove](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove).  I have not looked into how they do it.  Another library - [Poker C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8199/Poker-logic-in-C)

There are 133,784,560 unique 7 card hands. Some servers put them all in a database with a hand strength.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was a mathematical formula to work it out... Guess not.